# Add dynamic form validation callback to field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using formValidation.io and need to dynamically add a `callback` type validator within a class so that it can use a class property. The issue is that I initially pass my validator options into a `super` call that has some form validation procedures. But this means I do not have initial access to class properties.

So to do this I was trying to use `updateOption` but it definitely does not begin to validate this.

```
class MyForm extends Form {

  var validatorOptions = {
    fields: {
      phoneNumber: {
        validators: {
          regexp: {
            regexp: Regexp.phone,
            message: "Please enter a valid phone number"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  super({
    validator: {
      options: validatorOptions
    }
  });
  var self = this;

  this._cachedPhoneNumbers = [];

  var phoneValidatorCallback = {
    message: "This number is already in use",
    callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
      if ($.inArray(value, self._cachedPhoneNumbers) > -1)
        return false;
      return true;
    }
  }

  // ref to validator is definitely valid!
  this.validator.updateOption('phone', 'callback', 'callback', phoneValidatorCallback);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. I simply misused the function.

```
class MyForm extends Form {

  var validatorOptions = {
    fields: {
      phoneNumber: {
        validators: {
          regexp: {
            regexp: Regexp.phone,
            message: "Please enter a valid phone number"
          },
          callback: {
            message: 'This number is in use',
            callback: function() {
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  super({
    validator: {
      options: validatorOptions
    }
  });
  var self = this;

  this._cachedPhoneNumbers = [];

  function phoneValidatorCallback(value, validator, $field) {
    if ($.inArray(value, self._cachedPhoneNumbers) > -1)
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  // ref to validator is definitely valid!
  this.validator.updateOption('phone', 'callback', 'callback', phoneValidatorCallback);

}
```